# Preventing ajax-jquery loaded external file from caching in IE

Tags: ajax

I have this jquery script to call an external file. So far so good. The script is working fine, but as always IE makes what he wants. The external file that I load with this script (weather.php) is a file with real-time weather conditions data in it. Whit this script, I can refresh the div inside which is my weather.php file. And obviously I don't want IE to cache the data in this file. I want when someone click on button "REFRESH", the included page to be reloaded with the new data in it. In IE this doesn't happens because of the cache.
How can I change this script to not cache the div's content, or how can I say to my included file (weather.php) to do not cache it self?

This is the script:

```
function ajax_request() {
$('#column_weather').html('<img src="../images/home/ajax-loader.gif" width="16" height="11" style="vertical-align:middle;"/><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading...</b>');
$('#column_weather').load("../includes/home/weather.php");
```

}
`

And that's how I call the script:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ajax_request();return false;">Refresh</a>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a random variable on your query String

```
$('#column_weather').load("../includes/home/weather.php?myRand=" + guid());
```

I would make random var return a guid

```
function s4() {
       return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
}

function() guid{
       return s4()+s4()+"-"+s4()+"-"+s4()+"-"+s4()+"-"+s4()+s4()+s4();
}
```

Comment: Hi Zoidberg. Thanks for your opinion. I try your code, but when I added ?myRand=" + guid() and the next functions that you wright to me, the script stop working. The anchor started to return # in address bar, and stop refreshing the weather.php?

Comment: That is strange... is it something specific with the implementation of the php page?  I have done this many times, and it is used by YUI to prevent caching as well.  Maybe just try a random number and see.

Comment: Jesus!!! Thanks to JoshJordan, who reminds me that I have FireBug, I saw that a pieces of yours code are not in places, and I corrected them. Now your solutions works just fine!!! Thanks, and... call the price :)))

Comment: Glad it worked... sorry the code was incomplete.  I do now see a trailing bracket on the end.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just have proper caching instructions inside this weather.php file (to say not to cache it)

Comment: What if he didn't have access to the contents of that file?

Comment: Then the answer would have been different. But he references this file from the local path

Answer (score 0):

I would attach the current date and time as a GET parameter. Internet Explorer (and other browsers) view this information as critical to loading the page, just as any function returns a different value with different parameters. The trick is that you don't have to use the parameter. :)

```
$('#column_weather').load("../includes/home/weather.php?t=" + date());
```

Comment: Hi Josh. Thanks for your opinion. I try your code, but when I added ?t=" + date(), the script stop his work. The anchor started to return # after URL in address bar, and stop refreshing the weather.php?

Comment: I think you're going to need to do some debugging. Fire up the FireBug :)

Comment: Josh, thank you a lot, for this simple and obvious remind ;)))
Now everything is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a random parameter to the end of the query URL will help, but try adding this to the beginning of `weather.php`:

```
<?php 
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE); 
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for advise. I already try this, but it doesn't help at all. The weather.php, continued to be cached from IE.